# Control key in web browser on Mac

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't have a Mac, but I have seen its keyboard on pictures and there is a Control key. However the strange thing to me is that on most keyboards shortcuts, system/command key is used instead. Does the Control key on Mac behaves in exactly the same way as Ctrl key on Linux/Windows (in web browsers). To be more specifc, does it keyCode === 17 and does event.ctrlKey work for it?

I just want to implement Ctrl shortcuts for my web application and I'm wondering whether they will work on Macs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the keyCode for the Ctrl key is the same on Mac and PC (17).
The keyCode for the command key is 91.

From a usability point of view, Mac's user are not very used to use the Ctrl key since all the common shortcuts use the command key instead. So it would be good if your application support both.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. Are there any conflicts with the super key other than Chrome shortcuts? I know it's used for copy/paste too. On Linux Chrome you cannot use Ctrl + Tab, Q, W. Are there any system-wide Mac cmd+ shortcuts that cannot/shouldn't be overriden by a web app?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use this kind of shortcuts in a webapp. If you look at Gmail, Twitter or Facebook for example, they use just plain keys, not Ctrl+key combinations. I guess it's to avoid system-wide shortcuts conflicts.

Comment: @IvánGarcíaGarcía If you press `?` in Gmail, it shows lots of shortcuts with Command on Mac.